# redirect先を同じページにする

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

調べても見つからないので質問させていただきます。
redirect_toの使い方なんですが、こちらページを指定するのはできるんですが、同じページに遷移というか、ページ更新といったことってできますでしょうか？

やりたいことは、コントローラーにて、ある特定のアクションが起きた際にページ更新するということです。

複数のページにまたがるアクションがあって、毎回ページが移動されると手間がかかるのでできたらページの移動はさせたくないのですが、そんな方法ってありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 以降
`redirect_back(fallback_location: YOUR_PAGE)`

Rails 4 以前
`redirect_to :back`

で可能です。 YOUR_PAGEにはページへのパスを入れてください

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！そのやり方があったんですね！redirect_to :backは見つけてたんですがうまく動かなかったので諦めてましたw
それとなのですが、もしよろしければこの動作の時のnoticeの出し方などお分かりになりますでしょうか？
現在、format.html{redirect_back(fallback_location: store_path),notice:"この商品はお気に入りに登録できません"}
でやろうとしたのですがsyntaxエラーでてしまい、（）の位置や（、）など変えたりしてるのですがうまくいかないので。
一応今の所、,notice~を取り除けばうまく動いております。最悪nitice出さなくてもいいのですが、もしお分かりなら教えていただけると助かりますm(._.)m